# difference in declaring your string array

Tags: java, arrays, string

Whats the difference between this :

```
String [] columns = new String []{KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_DESC, KEY_TIME};
```

And This :

```
String [] columns={KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_DESC, KEY_TIME};
```

Comment: No difference. Most people prefer the second one because is sort of shorthand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line uses an array creation expression that contains an array initializer, and the second line contains just the array initializer.  Here, they perform the same exact function -- create and initialize an array.  But only one is only valid when declaring the array.

The [array initializer is defined in the JLS, Section 10.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6):

> An array initializer may be specified in a declaration (§8.3, §9.3, §14.4), or as part of an array creation expression (§15.10)
>
> ```
> ArrayInitializer:
>     { VariableInitializersopt ,opt }
>
> VariableInitializers:
>     VariableInitializer
>     VariableInitializers , VariableInitializer
> ```

and Section 15.10 defines the array creation expression to require `new SomeType[]`:

> An array creation expression is used to create new arrays (§10).
>
> ```
> ArrayCreationExpression:
>      new PrimitiveType DimExprs Dimsopt
>      new ClassOrInterfaceType DimExprs Dimsopt
>      new PrimitiveType Dims ArrayInitializer 
>      new ClassOrInterfaceType Dims ArrayInitializer
>
> DimExprs:
>      DimExpr
>      DimExprs DimExpr
>
> DimExpr:
>      [ Expression ]
>
> Dims:
>      [ ]
>      Dims [ ]
> ```

So, you can omit the `new SomeType[]` part if it's part of the declaration of the array variable, but you must include it elsewhere, such as an assignment expression.

Comment: so complicating....im still a baby to this java thing. However, Thanks for going so indepth.

Answer (score 1):

None.

The latter version is a handy shortcut syntax that will only work in declaration statements, but the result is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

They produce the same instantiation (only usable in declarations) of the string array, no difference at all in the result obtained. However, I mostly choose the first one (just a personal preference).

EDIT: Sorry, I was typing while the 1st answer appeared.